# Condition in class constructor c++

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, conditional-statements

I have to write a definition of class containg personal data (such as name, surname and age) with a condition that age cannot be less than 1. I was trying to catch an exeption in the class constuctor:

```
class Person {

public:
    Person (std::string name, std::string surname, int age) {
        try{
            this -> name = name;
            this -> surname = surname;
            this -> age = age;

            if(age < 1)
                throw std::string("Error! Age cannot be less than 1!");
       }

       catch(std::string ex){
           cout << ex << endl;
       }
};

private:
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    int age;
};
```

And that works fine but the most important thing is that **the object with age < 1 shouldn't be created at all** while with this solution I only get an error and object as person1("Thomas", "Something", -5) is still being created.

What is the best way to "block" the creation of objects which do not fulfil the condition?

Comment: Don't catch the exception. It doesn't make much sense to catch an exception as soon as you throw it tbh.

Comment: If you catch an exception, the language assumes you fix the error. If you can't fix it, don't catch and swallow it.

Comment: Catching (and not rethrowing) an exception tells the program that you handled the error. The exception will not propagate by itself.

Comment: To be clear, if you don't catch the exception, the object will not be created.

Comment: It is, in my opinion, generally unwise to raise exceptions in constructors. This is not what you do here, since you catch it as soon as you raise it, but I am cautioning you against raising it in the first place. Imagine a container class dynamically allocating `n` `Person`s and one of them throws an exception. If the container class's destructor cleans up after the class, that destructor will not be called because the container was not actually fully constructed.

Comment: @GarrettGutierrez 1) "_in my opinion, generally unwise to raise exceptions in constructors_" how will you handle the case, where an object can't be created for one reason or another? Why create an object in an invalid state, if you wouldn't be able to use it? 2) "_that destructor will not be called because the container was not actually fully constructed._" What's stopping you from catching the exception, cleaning up all of the used resources, and re-throwing the exception?

Comment: @GarrettGutierrez You can have more than one constructor. A "safer" constructor, that throws and a "quieter" constructor that builds valid but un-configured objects suitable for creation in an array.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius If you can remember to catch the exception in this hypothetical container's constructor, then you can also remember to validate input before constructing the `Person`s if this is so important to you. The problems arise when you either forget to catch the exception or remember to catch it but catch it somewhere other than the constructor of the container. Usually it is perfectly sufficient (and I am thus content) to leave such invalid objects to behave in a manner that is undefined or unspecified. Why not let someone create a person of -1 age, anyways?

Comment: @GarrettGutierrez I would really hate to see the code you are writing.. 1) Why should the calling code, validate the inputs of the code you are calling? This leads to multiple copy-paste's of the validation code (you don't typically, write a `class`, to be used once), while it should be in one place, where it makes the most sense. 2) You, surely, will "remember" to do error handling (i.e. will know what inputs are valid), while writing a class. You might not remember that, once you try to consume it several months after writing it.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius These problems are rather easily circumvented. If having to validate input is essential, write a `Person::isValid()` method and call this in the constructor or wherever else you want to check the validity of an instance. This allows you to control validation in a more graceful way, I think. As I said, a `Person` of `-1` age may be something you want to accommodate, which exemplifies the principle that usually there are much better ways of handling unexpected input than raising an exception. Creating a container of initial capacity `-10`? Just make it with capacity `0`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to guarantee you don't create an object with bad values is to throw an exception in the constructor, like you do. Only don't catch it, let it be caught by the code that is trying to create a bad object:

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person(std::string name, std::string surname, int age) {

        if(age < 1)
            throw std::string("Error! Age cannot be less than 1!");

        this->name = name;
        this->surname = surname;
        this->age = age;

    }

private:
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    int age;
};
```

As an aside, it is more usual to use the constructor's initialization list to initialize variables:

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person(std::string const& name, std::string const& surname, int age)
    : name(name), surname(surname), age(age) {

        if(age < 1)
            throw std::runtime_error("Error! Age cannot be less than 1!");
    }

private:
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    int age;
};
```

By throwing in the constructor you can guarantee that the object is valid when you use it:

```
int main()
{    
    try
    {
        Person p("John", "Doe", -5);

        // if we get here the person must be valid
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Also note I throw a [std::exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) derived object rather than a `std::string` as that is more idiomatic and recommended.

Comment: Consider `std::range_error`, which is derived from runtime_error.  A succinct reason for throwing `std::exception` derived objects would be that _the type of your exception object should describe the type of the exception_.  "string" doesn't do that.

Comment: @DrewDormann I did consider a range_error, but, on ballance, I thought that is probably more suitable for bad index values rather than dodgy user input (which could be a number or text).